# Firebase in Xamarin Forms return status WatingForActivation

Tags: forms, firebase, xamarin

I am a newbie with Xamarin Forms and Firebase.
I am writing a command to get data on Firebase Realtime Database.
Here is my "Main" code:

```
        authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(ApiKey));
        auth = authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("email", "pass").Result;
        auth = Task.Run(() => auth.GetFreshAuthAsync()).Result;
        firebase = new FirebaseClient(
        "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/",
        new FirebaseOptions
        {
            AuthTokenAsyncFactory = async () => (await auth.GetFreshAuthAsync()).FirebaseToken
        });
        var items = GetAllItem(firebase);
```

Here is my "GetAllItem()" code:

```
    public static async Task<List<Person>> GetAllItem(FirebaseClient firebaseClient)
    {
        return (await firebaseClient
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
          {
              Name = item.Object.Name,
          }).ToList();
    }
```

When I run my code, the result that I get like this image with "Status" = "WatingForActivation": 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfEe0.png

My Firebase DB' rule like this:

```
    {  
    /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. 
    */  
    "rules": {  
         ".read": "auth==null",  
         ".write":"auth==null"  
         }  
    }
```

So, any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change:**

```
var items = GetAllItem(GetAllItem);
```

**To:**

```
var items = await GetAllItem(GetAllItem);
```

[image]

If you need more code, you could download my project from `FirebaseDatabase/XamarinFirebase` folder on GitHub.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Comment: Thanks for helping. But this is what I get :)
[link](https://imgur.com/9R2CwbV)
What is that?